# How can i compare 2 arrays if they have simular elements?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I want to compare 2 arrays and check if they have 1 or more equal elements then I want to print this element like:

```
array1[a ,b ,c , d, e]
array2[e, r, t , a, v]

Console.println["a"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
var commonElements = array1.Intersect(array2).ToArray();
```

If `commonElements.Length>0` the arrays `array1` and `array2` have at least one common element.

Then you can print the common elements by just iterating through the items of the `commonElements` array.

```
foreach(var commonElement in commonElements)
    Console.WriteLine(commonElement);
```

Comment: but is there also a way too see what element they have in common>?

Comment: is there also a way to see what line this element is ?

Comment: @JordyHuijgens saying what line, what do you mean? You have an array of elements. If you want, you can get the index of the element in the array.

Comment: i mean like the array has like 10 elements and i want to know wich element it is f its the 1st 2nd 3rd ,, im sorry im really new with arrays

Comment: if this is my array: 

 [0]:    dog
    [1]:    lazy
    [2]:    the
    [3]:    over
    [4]:    jumps
    [5]:    fox
    [6]:    brown
    [7]:    quick
    [8]:    The

And i want to see wich string belongs to number 7 how can i do that?

Comment: You simply type this `array[7]`.

Comment: thats what i want but then backwards like array[quick]? i wanna do that with ther commonelements

Comment: @JordyHuijgens I am sorry, but I can't get you. `commonElements` is an array. Do you want to see what is stored in position with index 2? You just write this `commonElements[2]`. If there isn't any element in this position, the array's length is 2, it has two elements one in position 0 and one in position 1, then you will get an exception.

Comment: i want to know, how i can get the number of the line where my string is at i know the string but i dont know the line ,, u showed me Array[7] ,, but what i want to know is Array[brown] for example ,, the output should be 6 becouse when u look at the array : 

[0]: dog [1]: lazy [2]: the [3]: over [4]: jumps [5]: fox [6]: brown [7]: quick [8]

6 is brown

Comment: Ah, Then that you want is the array's method called `IndexOf`. `int index = Array.IndexOf(commonElements,"dog");`